AVGAS and motul 800 2t oil mixture
I am mixturing 1 liter of motul oil with 30 liters of avgas, the density of the mixture is 0.67 kg/l. Knowing that the AVGAS density is 0.72 Kg/l at 15 Celsius, and that I measured the mixture density at 30 Celsius, how much is the oil density?

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

According to the technical report of Motul brand posted here, density of Motul 800 2T at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ is $\pu{0.911 kg L-1}$ (for color red oil). However, there is no temperature profile for these synthetic motor oil can be found. Yet, since you have mixed in 30:1 ratio with the major component being AVGAS (which is a high-octane aviation fuel used for aircraft and racing cars), it is safe to assume the mixture may be behaving similar to AVGAS with temperature (with minimum difference). For instance, chemeurope.com has reported:

Avgas has a density of $\pu{6.02 lb/US gallon}$ at $\pu{15 ^\circ C}$, or $\pu{0.72 kg/l}$, and this density is commonly used for weight and balance computation. Density increases to $\pu{6.40 lb/US gallon}$ at $\pu{-40 ^\circ C}$, and decreases by about 0.5% per $\pu{5 ^\circ C}$ increase in temperature.

This information is trust worthy because this resource and Wikipedia provide the reference for the temperature increment rate (Wikipedia says the rate is 0.1% per $\pu{1 ^\circ C}$ increase in temperature, which is in agreement with European resource). Now, using your data, you may calculate the density of the mixture at $\pu{15 ^\circ C}$ using this rate.
